# AttributeError: 'Dato' object has no attribute 'dragPosition' Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo el siguiente problema, tengo el siguiente fragmento de código que lo utilizo para poder mover el MainWindow.

```
def mousePressEvent(self,event):
    if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
        self.dragPosition = event.globalPos() - self.frameGeometry().topLeft()
        event.accept()
def mouseMoveEvent(self,event):
    if event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
        self.move(event.globalPos()-self.dragPosition)
        event.accept()
```

sin embargo al ejecutar el programa, unicamente al dar click en el `QComboBox`, me arroja 2 errores,

1.- El primero es que si muevo por muy minimo el mouse al hacer click en el `QComboBox`, me arroja el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Angel\Desktop\Test\Login.py", line 87, in mouseMoveEvent
        self.move(event.globalPos()-self.dragPosition)
    AttributeError: 'Dato' object has no attribute 'dragPosition'
    [Finished in 28.2s with exit code 3]
```

2.- Cuando trato de volver a dar click al `QComboBox` se cambia de lugar:

Dejo un gif con los 2 problemas que genera...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el codigo completo de la aplicación:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
from PyQt5 import uic, QtCore, Qt
from Inicio import Inicio
from Firebase_load import *
from Registro import Image
from add_users import Usuarios
from es import user_name_1

class Principal(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi("Login.ui",self)
        self._Inicio = Inicio()
        self.registro = Image()
        self.add = Usuarios()

        self.combo_login ########## Este es el nombre de el QComboBox            

        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground,True)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_NoSystemBackground,False)

        self.closed.clicked.connect(lambda:self.close())
        self.mostrar_hora()

        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.timer.setInterval(1000)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.mostrar_hora)
        self.timer.start()

    def mostrar_hora(self):
        self.hora.setText(QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime().toString("hh:mm:ss AP"))



class Dato(Principal):
    def __init__(self):
        Principal.__init__(self)
        self.b_login.clicked.connect(self.validate_User)

    def validate_User(self):
        user = self.l_usuario.text()

        if user == '':
            self.l_status.setText('No se ingreso un usuario')
        else:
            ref = db.reference("/usuarios/")
            res = ref.get()

            for key in res.items():
                if key[0] == user:
                    self.validate_password(user)
    def validate_password(self,user):
        password  = self.l_password.text()

        refp = db.reference("/usuarios/"+user)
        res = refp.get()

        for key in res.items():
            if key[0] == 'password':
                if key[1] == password:
                    self.other()
                    self.l_status.setText("login")
                    pass
                else:
                    self.l_password.setText('')
                    self.l_status.setText("Invalidate Password")
            elif key[0] == 'permisos':
                self.registro.acces = int(key[1])
                self.add.acces = int(key[1])



    def other(self):

        self.close()
        user_name_1(self.l_usuario.text())
        self._Inicio.user_online_on(self.l_usuario.text())
        self._Inicio.user.setText(self.l_usuario.text())
        self._Inicio.show()

    def mousePressEvent(self,event):
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.dragPosition = event.globalPos() - self.frameGeometry().topLeft()
            event.accept()
    def mouseMoveEvent(self,event):
        if event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.move(event.globalPos()-self.dragPosition)
            event.accept()

app = QApplication([])
p = Dato()
p.show()
app.exec_()
```

Login.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <ui version="4.0">
   <class>MainWindow</class>
   <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>0</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <width>351</width>
      <height>551</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="windowTitle">
     <string>MainWindow</string>
    </property>
    <property name="windowIcon">
     <iconset>
      <normaloff>icono.ico</normaloff>icono.ico</iconset>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">background:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));</string>
    </property>
    <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
     <property name="styleSheet">
      <string notr="true">background:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));</string>
     </property>
     <widget class="QFrame" name="frame">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>0</x>
        <y>90</y>
        <width>351</width>
        <height>461</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true">background:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.494249, y1:0, x2:0.472, y2:1, stop:0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 202), stop:1 rgba(51, 51, 51, 218));</string>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShape">
       <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShadow">
       <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
      </property>
      <widget class="QLabel" name="login">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>10</x>
         <y>180</y>
         <width>161</width>
         <height>31</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <pointsize>14</pointsize>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">QLabel#login{
  background:None;
  color:white;
  }</string>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>Login</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QLabel" name="icono_usuario">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>10</x>
         <y>230</y>
         <width>32</width>
         <height>32</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">QLabel#icono_usuario{
  background:#7A7B7F;
  border:0px;
  background-image:url(Images/usuario.png)
  }</string>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string/>
       </property>
       <property name="pixmap">
        <pixmap>new/Imagenes/usuario.png</pixmap>
       </property>
       <property name="alignment">
        <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QLabel" name="icono_contrasena">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>10</x>
         <y>280</y>
         <width>32</width>
         <height>32</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">QLabel#icono_contrasena{
  background:#7A7B7F;
  border :0px;
  background-image:url(Images/pss.png);
  background-repeat:none;
  background-position:center;
  }</string>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string/>
       </property>
       <property name="pixmap">
        <pixmap>new/Imagenes/pss.png</pixmap>
       </property>
       <property name="scaledContents">
        <bool>false</bool>
       </property>
       <property name="alignment">
        <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QLineEdit" name="l_password">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>42</x>
         <y>280</y>
         <width>291</width>
         <height>32</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <pointsize>10</pointsize>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">QLineEdit#l_password{
  border:0px;
  background:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.494249, y1:0, x2:0.472, y2:1, stop:0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 183), stop:1 rgba(157, 157, 157, 94));
  color:white;
  }</string>
       </property>
       <property name="inputMethodHints">
        <set>Qt::ImhHiddenText|Qt::ImhNoAutoUppercase|Qt::ImhNoPredictiveText|Qt::ImhSensitiveData</set>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string/>
       </property>
       <property name="echoMode">
        <enum>QLineEdit::Password</enum>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QLineEdit" name="l_usuario">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>42</x>
         <y>230</y>
         <width>291</width>
         <height>32</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <pointsize>10</pointsize>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">QLineEdit#l_usuario{
  border:0px;
  background:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.494249, y1:0, x2:0.472, y2:1, stop:0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 183), stop:1 rgba(157, 157, 157, 94));
  color:white;
  }</string>
       </property>
       <property name="inputMask">
        <string/>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string/>
       </property>
       <property name="cursorPosition">
        <number>0</number>
       </property>
       <property name="placeholderText">
        <string/>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QPushButton" name="b_login">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>240</x>
         <y>380</y>
         <width>91</width>
         <height>31</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <pointsize>9</pointsize>
         <weight>50</weight>
         <bold>false</bold>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">QPushButton#b_login{
  border:0px;
  background:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.494249, y1:0, x2:0.472, y2:1, stop:0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 255), stop:1 rgba(234, 234, 234, 255));
  }


  }
  QPushButton#b_login:hover{
  border:0px;
  background:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.494249, y1:0, x2:0.472, y2:1, stop:0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 255), stop:1 rgba(200, 200, 200, 255));

  }
  QPushButton#b_login:pressed{
  border:0px;
  background:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.494249, y1:0, x2:0.472, y2:1, stop:0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 255), stop:1 rgba(234, 234, 234, 255));
  border-bottom:2px solid grey;</string>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>Login</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QPushButton" name="closed">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>320</x>
         <y>0</y>
         <width>31</width>
         <height>23</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <pointsize>9</pointsize>
         <weight>75</weight>
         <bold>true</bold>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">QPushButton#closed{
  background:None;
  border:0px;
  color:lightgrey;
  }
  QPushButton#closed:hover{
  color:#D8211D;
  }</string>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>X</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QLabel" name="hora">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>0</x>
         <y>440</y>
         <width>101</width>
         <height>20</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <pointsize>10</pointsize>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">QLabel#hora{
  background:None;
  color:white;
  }</string>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string/>
       </property>
       <property name="alignment">
        <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QLabel" name="l_status">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>60</x>
         <y>330</y>
         <width>231</width>
         <height>21</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">QLabel#l_status{
  background:None;
  color:white;
  }</string>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string/>
       </property>
       <property name="alignment">
        <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QComboBox" name="combo_login">
       <property name="enabled">
        <bool>true</bool>
       </property>
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>150</x>
         <y>360</y>
         <width>50</width>
         <height>17</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">QComboBox#combo_login{
  background:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
  border:0px;
  color:white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightblue;
  }


  QComboBox QAbstractItemView
  {
      border: 2px solid darkgray;
      background:grey;
      color: black;
      selection-background-color: QLinearGradient( x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1, stop: 0 #111, stop: 1 #333);
  }
  QComboBox#combo_login::drop-down
  {
       subcontrol-origin: padding;
       subcontrol-position: top right;
       width: 15px;
       color: white;
       border-left-width: 0px;
       border-left-color: darkgray;
       border-left-style: solid; /* just a single line */
       border-top-right-radius: 3px; /* same radius as the QComboBox */
       border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
       padding-left: 10px;
   }</string>
       </property>
       <item>
        <property name="text">
         <string>exe1</string>
        </property>
       </item>
       <item>
        <property name="text">
         <string>exe2</string>
        </property>
       </item>
       <item>
        <property name="text">
         <string>exe3</string>
        </property>
       </item>
      </widget>
     </widget>
     <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>90</x>
        <y>10</y>
        <width>181</width>
        <height>171</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true">background:url(Images/Login.png);
  background-repeat:none;
  background-position:center;</string>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string/>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </widget>
   </widget>
   <resources/>
   <connections/>
  </ui>
```

Comment: podrias compartir el archivo Login.ui

Comment: He tratado de reproducir tu error pero no he podido, seria bueno que te tomes el tiempo y proveas un  real [mcve], pienso que ya tienes la suficiente saber lo que es. :)

Comment: @eyllanesc, claro ya subi el archivo login.ui

Comment: Por favor elimina las cosas que no estan definidas, un [mcve] no debe depender de un codigo externo, por eso se dice que debe ser completo

Comment: Acabo de probar tu código con Login.ui comentando los imports que generan errores y aun no puedo reproducir su error ¿esta seguro que ese es código que genera el error?

Comment: @eyllanesc, el error desaparece cuando elimino las funciones, mousePressEvent y mouseMoveEvent, pero evidentemente no puedo mover la venta principal

Comment: Yo no he tenido problemas, si deseas ayuda debes mejorar tu [mcve], quizas los imports que he comentado eviten que se generen los errores.

Comment: @eyllanesc, no no son lo simports, ya los descarte, y lo del ejemplo pues no se que mas subir es que ese es el archivo que me da problemas

Comment: Bueno, yo no puedo reproducir el error, pero seria genial que perfecciones tu [mcve]

Comment: @eyllanesc, ok muchas gracias por la ayuda de todas formas

Comment: Lo ultimo yo solo lanzo la aplicación y la muevo, no presiono ningun boton, ni relleno nada en los QLineEdits, etc ya que generarian errores por las importaciones.

Comment: @eyllanesc, O hay alguna manera de aislar el QComboBox, del evento mouseMoveEvent ¿?, es decir que no se ejecute ese evento si el click esta dentro del qcombobox

Comment: @eyllanesc,hay alguna manera de aislar el QComboBox, del evento mouseMoveEvent ¿?, es decir que no se ejecute ese evento si el click esta dentro del qcombobox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La causa de este comportamiento es que el evento "Press" no es propagado al padre desde el hijo, pero si lo es el evento "Move" cuando, manteniendo pulsado el botón izquierdo, sacamos el cursor de los límites del botón (**pasa tanto con el `QPushButton` como con el botón del `QComboBox`**).

Voy a aclara que en Linux (probado en ArchLinux con KDE Plasma) no hay forma de reproducir el problema con el `QComboBox` al menos en mi caso, ahora bién, en Windows 10 el comportamiento es completamente distinto porque la lista de opciones no se superpone al botón y el evento "Move" se propaga al padre cuando rebasamos los límites del botón del `QComboBox` (el problema no ocurre dentro de la lista desplegable). Lo anterior ocasiona el comportamiento indeseado mostrado, al permitir el arrastre de la ventana cuando el click se originó en el `QComboBox`, pero además, éste se despliega en posiciones erráticas al soltar el botón izquierdo del ratón.

El error:

> AttributeError: 'Dato' object has no attribute 'dragPosition'

es causado porque se produce el evento "Move" sin que previamente tuviera lugar el evento "Press" en el padre, como defines el atributo `dragPosition` en `mousePressEvent` cuando se llama `mouseMoveEvent` e intenta usar `self.dragPosition` este no existe aún. Por eso el error no se produce si previamente a desplegar el `QComboBox` hacemos click en la ventana, en este caso el atributo ya está definido, pero no actualizado por `mousePressEvent`, lo que causa que `dragPosition` no tenga la posición de este último click, sino la del anterior,  causando el "salto" apreciado en el GIF.

Como recomendación, no crees nunca atributos de instancia fuera del `__init__`, aunque solo sean usados por unos métodos determinados inicializalos siempre en el `__init__` (a `None` si no quieres darles un valor), no los crees en los otros métodos.

El problema se puede solucionar de varias formas, por ejemplo asegurándonos antes de procesar `mouseMoveEvent` de que llegó previamente un evento "Press" a la ventana (dado que este es bloqueado por el botón):

```
class Dato(Principal):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._on_drag = None   # <<<<<<<<<<<<< No te olvides de esto

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self._drag_pos= event.globalPos() - self.frameGeometry().topLeft()
            event.accept()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton and self._drag_pos is not None:
            self.move(event.globalPos() - self._drag_pos)
            event.accept()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self._drag_pos = None      
            event.accept()
```

Otra opción es simplemente bloquear la propagación de los eventos del ratón al padre mediante el atributo `QtCore.Qt.WA_NoMousePropagation`:

```
class Dato(Principal):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.combo_login.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_NoMousePropagation)
        # Resto del código
```

Comment: muchas gracias llevava mucho tiempo tratando de arreglar esto